# Prevent false condition from being evaluated

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created an excel formula that convert a string into a date.

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

It's working as expected when a value is specified but blank cell are giving me an error so I added an IF to handle those cells.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2)))
```

The problem with the IF keyword is that both true and false parts seems to be evaluated.  In this specific case the LEFT / MID / RIGHT keyword will each raise an error even if the "" should be used.

Is is possible to tell the IF keyword to evaluate only the value that will be used based on it's condition?

P.S. I had to convert the formula from a french version of Excel... if there's any typo please let me know.

Comment: does A1 contain a formula that returns `""`  IF does not care if the side it does not use evaluated to an error.

Comment: And you seem to missing a `)` on both your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Prevent false condition from being evaluated

False conditions are not evaluated in Excel formulas.

You likely have cells looking to be blank, but not being really blank (e.g. contain formula or `'`)

Instead of ISBLANK, use `A1=""`

Comment: Indeed, some cells had some invisible characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have success using the same formula as yours

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Input_Text), "", DATE(LEFT(Input_Text,4), MID(Input_Text, 5, 2), RIGHT(Input_Text, 2)))
```

- When `Input_Text` is `20100203`, I get `2/3/2010`
- When `Input_Text` is blank, I get a blank cell

Not sure why your version doesn't work. Perhaps there is some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `IFERROR` Function to avoid display of Error Type of Messages

```
=IFERROR(Formula,"")
```